# Performing the inverse of (or reversing) bitwise OR in C#

Tags: c#, .net, operators, bit-manipulation

How do I perform the inverse of the bitwise OR ( `|=` ) operator in C#? Is there a NOR bitwise operator in C# that I can use?

**Scenario:**

I am inheriting a base class from the .NET framework. This class has an operation which is setting a flag.

**Example:** `flags |= 0x200;`

In my derived class, I want to omit this flag setting, as if the operation `flags |= 0x200;` had never happened.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can AND (`&`) with the inverse (`~`) of the value you want to remove:

```
flags &= ~0x200;
```

If you intention is to ensure that this flag is not set. If you want to undo a previous change to this flag, then as @Russell says, XOR may be what you're after.

Answer (score 6):

You can XOR the flag to remove it

```
flags ^= 0x200
```

This same operation will also turn that flag ON if it's off. XORing with masks behaves as a toggle.

Answer (score 2):

wouldn't an XOR work? `flags ^ 0x200`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I disagree - I'm stating in a polite way that undoing a bitwise operation like that can be done with an XOR, which is what the poster was asking I think.

Comment: @RussellTroywest, your answer has been helpful! Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

It would be hard for you to know if original value of flags had those bits set or not. Say flags was already `0x200` when your code executes then your operation will not change anything any xor nor and nor or will ensure previous value to be retrieved. The one way I see is to make this operation in virtual method and override it in derived class without making any changes. The other way would be to make this magic value a property and set it in derived class constructor to 0. That will prevent the change.